# Send commands to Linux terminal with PuTTY

Tags: linux, terminal, putty

How can I send a command (not to open a file) with PuTTY that will run on a Linux terminal?

For example:

```
putty.exe 10.31.2.121 -l root -pw password | echo "Hi"
```

So that I will see the "Hi" on the Linux console?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/587629/putty-run-a-remote-command-after-login-keep-the-shell-running/587663#587663

Answer (score 3):

Use plink.exe (from the developer of PuTTY).

And do something like the following

```
C:\putty\plink.exe user1@192.168.0.1 -pw P@55W0rD!
```

-m command.txt

I took this from *[Automate Cisco SSH connections with plink on Windows](http://simple-webdesign.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/automate-cisco-ssh-connections-with.html)*.